# horizontalPager with Card View jetpack compose cotain 3 cards

Tags: android, jetpack

Nned to create one horizontal pager which have three cards and the central card contain 80% of width and left and right card contain 10% of a screen with please suggest any solution for this

tried standard horizontal pager but animation is working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.